# Reading CSV files and writing to known locations in specific sheets

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am reading CSV files.

One method, commented out in code below, is very slow.

The other method writes text rather than numeric data into my sheet(s). I get the little error triangles in each cell where the data is written. The data looks correct but it cannot be manipulated (summed, truncated ...) unless I double click my mouse on each cell.

All my data is numeric and in "tabular" form.

This image shows a small section of data written to `Sheets("Input_Data")`
[image]

```vb
Sub Read_Data()

Dim lines As Variant
Dim FilePath_1, FilePath_2 As Variant
Dim LineFromFile As String

Dim j, i, row_number, Records_Line, Length_Line As Integer
Dim LineItems As Variant

FilePath_1 = "C:\Users\peter\Documents\Julia_Code\Greenhouse_Model\Green-Lights-main\DetailedOutput_Crop.csv"
    
row_number = 0

Open FilePath_1 For Input As #1     ' Open file for input

Line Input #1, LineFromFile ' skip heading line
LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ",")
Records_Line = UBound(LineItems)

Do Until EOF(1)     ' Loop until end of file.
    Line Input #1, LineFromFile
    
    LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ",")    'array dimensions starts from 0

'    For j = 0 To Records_Line
'        Sheets("Data_Input").Cells(row_number + 1, j + 1).Value2 = LineItems(j)
'    Next j

    With Worksheets("Data_Input")
        .Range(.Cells(row_number + 1, 1), .Cells(row_number + 1, Records_Line + 1)).Value = LineItems

    End With
    
    row_number = row_number + 1
    
Loop

Close #1 ' Close file.
End Sub
```

Comment: Not the solution but note that if you declare `Dim j, i, row_number, Records_Line, Length_Line As Integer` only `Length_Line` is of type `Integer` but all the others are of type `Variant`! In VBA you need to specify a type for **all** variables: `Dim j As Long, i As Long, row_number An Long, Records_Line As Long, Length_Line  As Long`

Comment: Thank you. I will take note in future. Regards Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub Read_Data()
 Dim arrCSV, dataCSV, cols, FilePath_1 As String, strSeparator As String
 Dim nrRows As Long, i As Long, nL As Long, C As Long, ws As Worksheet

 FilePath_1 = "C:\Users\peter\Documents\Julia_Code\Greenhouse_Model\Green-Lights-main\DetailedOutput_Crop.csv"
 
 strSeparator = vbCrLf 'it must be changed (vbCr, vbLf) if nrRows does not match the expected number...

 'put all the csv file content in an array of rows, in one step:
 arrCSV = Split(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(FilePath_1, 1).ReadAll, strSeparator)
 nrRows = UBound(arrCSV): cols = Split(arrCSV(0), ",") 'necessary to redim the final array 
 ReDim dataCSV(0 To nrRows - 1, 0 To UBound(cols)) 'the final array to be loaded
 
    nL = 0
    For i = 0 To nrRows - 1
        cols = Split(arrCSV(i), ",") 'extract the row elements
        For C = 0 To UBound(cols)
            dataCSV(nL, C) = cols(C) 'fill each array row
        Next
        nL = nL + 1                  'increment the array row
    Next i
    
    Set ws = Worksheets("Data_Input")
    ws.cells.Clear 'supposing that it should drop the content in its first cell

    'Drop the array content at once (very fast comparing with each line dropping):
    ws.Range("A1").Resize(nrRows, UBound(dataCSV, 2) + 1).Value = dataCSV
    MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

I must confess that I took it like a challenge, but may I know why don't you simple open the csv file in Excel? Do you need dropping the content on the first empty line and use the code for more such files, the presented one being only an example?

Comment: I have four CSV files to read in (all quite large ) and each is written to specific locations in various sheets. The excel program is used as a GUI to prepare data for a Julia script. Julia solves the program and then generates *.csv files that are then read back into excel (through a VBA script) . Many thanks for your help. Your script works - I will need to make some changes to suit my needs. Regards  Peter

Comment: FaneDuru many thanks again. Just ticked the box. The read in speed is impressive compared to what I was getting with my old code. I am very sure this code will be useful to others. Peter